# Search for DOM Element's attribute using onClick(event) isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating DOM elements programatically using unique IDs provided by a server. I need to fetch the attribute named `posterId` when clicking over one of them.

I am attempting to pass the event currently to no avail.

I have tried using:

- `onClick="handlePosterClick(event)`
- `onClick="handlePosterClick(this)`
- `onClick=handlePosterClick(this.posterId)`

This function generates all of the Divs and elements that compose the entire block:

```html
function createMovieDivForCarrousel(){
    var carrousel = '';
    for(var j = 0; j < movieGenres.length; j++){
        //creates a slider, section title and defines mouseovers
        carrousel += '<div class="slider"><h3>'+movieGenres[j]+'</h3><span onmouseover="scrollL()" onmouseout="clearScroll()" class="handle handlePrev active"><i class="fa fa-caret-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><div id="scroller" class="row"><div class="row__inner">';
        for(var i = 0; i < recommendedMovies.length; i++){
            if(recommendedMovies[i].genre[0].toLowerCase() == movieGenres[j].toLowerCase()){
                carrousel +='<div class="gui-card"><div class="gui-card__media"><img class="gui-card__img" src="'+recommendedMovies[i].poster+'"/></div><div class="gui-card__details" "posterId="'+recommendedMovies[i].id+'" onClick="handlePosterClick(event)"><div class="gui-card__title">'+recommendedMovies[i].title+'</div></div></div>';
            }
        }
        carrousel += '</div></div><span onmouseover="scrollR()" onmouseout="clearScroll()"  class="handle handleNext active"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div>';
    }
    return carrousel;
}
```

This function handles what it is supposed to do with it, I have suppressed the unnecessary parts but just attempting to log the value does not work either:

```html
function handlePosterClick(e) { 
    var indexOfClicked = search(e.target.getAttribute("posterId"));
    posterArray[indexOfClicked].state = !posterArray[indexOfClicked].state;
}

window.onclick = e => {}
```

The element that holds both the ID and the function call is:

```html
<div class="gui-card__details" "posterId="'+recommendedMovies[i].id+'" onClick="handlePosterClick(event)">
```

For reference, the IDs go from 1 to 118 and they are all unique.

---

Edit: doing `onClick="console.log(this)"` and clicking over one of the elements print the following:

`<div class="gui-card__details" "posterid="11" onclick="console.log(this)"><div class="gui-card__title">Manchester by the Sea&nbsp;(2016)</div></div>`

Removing the extra double-quotes and making it `posterId` rather than `"posterId"` also yields `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`. I was unsure how to represent and that was the last state of the snippet.

Comment: Is the extra " sign `"posterid` a typo here? Or is it also in your code? Might be causing the problem.

Comment: Do you mean the one on my edit? It is not a typo, when I output the object it gives me that as well. I have also attempted using `toLowerCase()` when I first noticed they were different, but the result was the same. I either get `undefined` or `null` when attempting to access it within the function. Having the `onClick` print itself works.

Comment: If you mean the extra double-quotes, it also gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` without them. I thought it could be a representation issue so I left them there because it was the last thing I tried

Comment: Well, as the console.log shows when you pass `this`, you are passing the clicked element. So the issue is whatever is causing the error with the extra quotes in `"posterId`. Follow the error stack in your browser's devtools and see what's causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems:
1. The extra double quotes are causing a problem. It is hiding a different problem. First, remove those extra double quotes before posterId.
2. Either `search` isn't finding the index or the index is pointing to a null/undefined in the array. You need to debug those two parts of the code.

Comment: Removing the double quotes and changing from passing an event to the object itself did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try use 
document.getElementsByName("posterId");
inside the handlePosterClick()

Comment: I have 118 elements with the same tag (only different values). How would returning the element by tag provide me with the one that triggered the onClick event?